# i.imgur.com is killing network connections

Tags: networking

Other people don't seem to have this problem.  If I telnet in to i.imgur.com it disconnects me even for very simple requests.

```
bash-4.0$ host i.imgur.com
i.imgur.com is an alias for wpc.4220.edgecastcdn.net.
wpc.4220.edgecastcdn.net is an alias for gs1.wpc.edgecastcdn.net.
gs1.wpc.edgecastcdn.net has address 72.21.81.253
bash-4.0$ telnet i.imgur.com  80
Trying 72.21.81.253...
Connected to i.imgur.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: i.imgur.com

Connection closed by foreign host.
bash-4.0$
```

Any hints?

Comment: could it be related to recent amazon downtime? just guessing

Comment: Does an https connection work?

Comment: And https connection seems to work.  I get a 404 not found, but that's a lot better than a blunt connection closed.

Comment: From all the downvotes apparently this is a hated question. Is there a better forum?

Comment: Not a hated question. just an unanswerable one.  We're not fans of unanswerable questions.

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing what you did exactly, and both times (using HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1) the server gave me a 302 Found error redirecting back to the main imgur site. Now, maybe the server just came back up, or maybe they fixed a faulty configuration, or maybe your current network simply doesn't allow connections to i.imgur.com. There are plenty of reasons why this can't be working.